# SQL Server : How to get same "parent" value for all children

Tags: sql, sql-server

In my table I have 3 columns like below:

```
No.        | Type   |   Amount
-------------------------------
110200014  |    A   | 19,259.00
110200014  |    D   | -802.46
110200014  |    D   | -1,604.92
```

Type A is for parent record, type D is for children record.

As a result in my request I would like all lines to show "19,259.00" in "amount" column. What is important for me is to get that "parent" value for all children

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
;
WITH cte
AS (
    SELECT *
    FROM TABLE
    WHERE type = 'A'
    )
SELECT cte.Amount, Table.*
FROM TABLE
INNER JOIN cte
    ON TABLE.No = cte.no
WHERE TABLE.type = 'D'
```

---

Using the data generated by @ScubaManDan

The following works:

```
create table #tempTab(Num int,rtype char(1),amount decimal(8,2));

insert into #tempTab values(110200014,'A',19259.00)
insert into #tempTab values(110200014,'D',-802.46)
insert into #tempTab values(110200014,'D',-1604.92)

;WITH cte
AS (
    SELECT *
    FROM #tempTab
    WHERE rtype = 'A'
    )
SELECT cte.Amount, #tempTab.*
FROM #tempTab
INNER JOIN cte
    ON #tempTab.Num = cte.Num
WHERE #tempTab.rtype = 'D'
```

Produces:

```
Amount  Num rtype   amount
------------------------------------
19259.00    110200014   D   -802.46
19259.00    110200014   D   -1604.92
```

Comment: @Radu, you are too quick!

Comment: @user3656218 Just choose the columns you are looking for in the "second" part of the query.

Comment: I am always on S.O., following SQL questions, moderating etc.

Comment: @ Anthony Home : second part meaning beggining from SELECT cte.Amount?

Comment: Correct, i.e. the Table.{fields}

Comment: I am sorry guys but i am still having trouble .. this query works but only gives me the "parent" and I lose all the children .. any idea?

Comment: Run the CTE part first to confirm you are getting the parents you seek, i.e. ;
WITH cte
AS (
    SELECT *
    FROM TABLE
    WHERE type = 'A'
    )
SELECT Table.*
FROM TABLE

Comment: common table expression defined but not used

Comment: Apologies: ; WITH cte AS ( SELECT * FROM TABLE WHERE type = 'A' ) SELECT * FROM cte

Comment: I confirm that I get the parents I seek with this

Comment: Make sure you are referring to the correct "type" on the last line.  For now take out that line, just to see if you are getting data.  I have updated the code above.

Comment: If I get rid of the last line I get all the parents line. If i add the last line (with the correct type) i get no line

Comment: Obviously I am using ScubaMan's data scripts for testing and I am not expecting you to use that.  The concept works though.  I can only think that the 'D' has spaces or something.  Maybe do a rtrim(type) = rtrim(type)

Answer (score 1):

How about something like this:

```
create table #tempTab(Num int,rtype char(1),amount decimal(8,2));

insert into #tempTab values
(110200014,'A',19259.00),
(110200014,'D',-802.46),
(110200014,'D',-1604.92)

select * 
from #tempTab t
cross apply (select amount from #tempTab where rtype = 'A' and Num = t.Num) pa;
```

Comment: The problem is I do not wish to create any temp or new table

Comment: That was just to create the example.  You wouldn't of course, run the temp table bits, just the last select statement, and alter it according to the table that YOU have, instead of the example temporary table.

Comment: I did that for anyone who stumbles over this thread so that they can create the example to query from as well.